# R: Splitting one list into two lists under a condition

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I've one large  list (assume L) with `20` dataframes. The `20` data frames have only two different forms. They have `13` or `5` rows.

```
$foo1

     a  value
1   12  321.12
2   11  231.12 
3   10  211.15
4    9  ...
5    8  ...
6    7  ...
7    6
8    5
9    4
10   3 
11   2
12   1
13   0

$foo2

  a  value
1 4  19.52
2 3  98.91
3 2  97.67
4 1  ...
5 0  ...
```

I want to split the list into two lists with the following condition:

All data frames with the same row length should be stored in one list. As a result, I want a list of all data frames that have `5` rows and the other one should include all data frames with `13` rows.

Comment: Try `grp <- sapply(L, nrow); split(L, grp)`

Comment: Wow that was fast thanks :) Is there a way to assign names to the two lists in the split function ?

Comment: What would be the names you wanted?  Let's say you have foo1, foo3 etc. are 13 rows and foo2, foo4 are 5 rows, then

Comment: month (for the list with row length 13) and quarter (for the list with row length 5). Acutally my list has the following names $`5`$foo1 $`5`$foo2,....., $`13`$foo6..... I want to store the lists into two different variables. For that I first wanted to assign the two names two the lists

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by `split`ting on the number of rows.  Create a grouping variable by looping through the `list` to get the number of rows ('grp')

```
grp <- sapply(L, nrow)
```

Then `split` the `list` 'L' by the grp

```
L1 <- split(L, grp)
```

If we need the `list` names to be 'month', 'quarter'

```
L1 <- split(L, setNames(c("month", "quarter"), c("13", "5"))[as.character(grp)])
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
L <- list(foo1 = data.frame(a = 1:13, value = rnorm(13)),
         foo2 = data.frame(a = 1:5, value = rnorm(5)),
         foo3 = data.frame(a = 1:13, value = rnorm(13)),
         foo4 = data.frame(a = 1:5, value = rnorm(5)))
```

>